# Android fragments with Activitys that display OpenGL es 2.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, opengl-es

I have a dialog that I want to display, and I cannot. The activity that I'm calling it from has an opengl es SurfaceViewRenderer. Some code is below. The text 'here' shows, and some of the activity from the fragment is going on in the background (I see some of the println statements from there) but no fragment is visible. I do not see 'is visible' in the logs.

```
public void goToFrag() {

    dDial = new MYDialogFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    dDial.setArguments(args);

    dDial.show(getFragmentManager(), "dDialog");

    if (dDial.isVisible() ) System.out.println("is visible");

    System.out.println("here");

}
```

so here's some more info. I tried to run the 'goToFrag()' method from the 'runOnUIThread()' method and the fragment appears, but only for a second. Then the PlayActivity (what I'm calling the activity that launches the Fragment and contains the GLSurfaceRenderer) disappears. After that I'm back at the activity that calls the PlayActivity. There's no error output that I can find.

```
//from OpenGL SurfaceViewRenderer...

public void goToFrag() {
    mPlayActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mPlayActivity.goToFrag();
        }
    });

}
```

More code might help

```
public class APDuellingDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public boolean mDebugMessages = true;
    public OnFragmentReturnListener mListener;
    public View v;
    public ListView mListView;
    public RadioGroup radio_left_right;

    public interface OnFragmentReturnListener {

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
    }


    public APDuellingDialogFragment() {
        mBT = new APDuellingBluetooth(this);

        mList = new ArrayList<APDuellingBluetooth.MenuItem>();
        mSocketsLaunched = false;
    }

    public static APDuellingDialogFragment newInstance() {
        APDuellingDialogFragment dialog = new APDuellingDialogFragment();
        //dialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.AppTheme);
        dialog.setShowsDialog(true);
        dialog.setRetainInstance(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        if (mDebugMessages) System.out.println("on attach");

        //...

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentReturnListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (mDebugMessages) System.out.println("on create");


    }



    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ap_dueling, container, false);

            if (mDebugMessages) System.out.println("on create view");

        }



        Button button_close = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.duel_button_close);
        button_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


                dismiss();
            }
        });

        Button button_rescan = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.duel_button_rescan);
        button_rescan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if(mBT.isBluetoothSupported()) {

                    //...
                }

            }
        });

        radio_left_right = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.duel_right_left_group);
        radio_left_right.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                //...
            }
        });


        Switch switch_audio = (Switch) v.findViewById(R.id.duel_switch_sound);
        switch_audio.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                //...

            }
        });

        mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                //...

                return false;
            }
        });

        return v;
    }



    public void restartGameFromFragment() {

        if(mDebugMessages) System.out.println("restartgamefrom fragment");

        Intent mIntent = prepareIntentForGame();

        mListener.onActivityResult(AP.INTENT_ACTIVITY_DUEL_SETUP, Activity.RESULT_OK, mIntent);

        dismiss();
    }

    public Intent prepareIntentForGame() {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent();
        //...
        return mIntent;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();


        if (mDebugMessages) System.out.println("on destroy");
    }

}
```

finally this:

```
public class MYActivityPlay extends Activity implements MYDuellingDialogFragment.OnFragmentReturnListener {
    private MYGLSurfaceView myMYView;
    public MYButtonManager mButtons;

    public MYReadXML mXML;

    public MYDuellingDialogFragment duelDialogFragment;

    public RelativeLayout mTitleAndScoresView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mIntent = this.getIntent();
        mMode = mIntent.getIntExtra(MY.INTENT_MODE_CONSTANT, MY.MODE_PLAY);
        mIntentLevel = mIntent.getIntExtra(MY.INTENT_LEVEL_CONSTANT, 1);
        mScore = mIntent.getLongExtra(MY.INTENT_SCORE_CONSTANT, 0);
        mHealth = mIntent.getIntExtra(MY.INTENT_HEALTH_CONSTANT, MYDirector.FULL_HEALTH_CONST);
        mPlayButtonPressedCount = mIntent.getIntExtra(MY.INTENT_PLAY_PRESSED_CONSTANT, 0);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        startSurfaceView();
        if (mMode == MY.MODE_DUEL) goToFrag(); // <--here is problem!!
    }

    @Override
    public  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //....
    }



    public void startSurfaceView() {
        if (true ) {

            Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            mButtons = new MYButtonManager(this.getApplicationContext(), size.x ,size.y );
            MYSound mSounds = new MYSound(this);

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService
                    (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View mTitleAndScore = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_title_score,  null);

            myMYView = new MYGLSurfaceView(/*some stuff here*/);
            RelativeLayout mRelative = new RelativeLayout(this);

            mRelative.addView(myMYView);
            mRelative.addView(mTitleAndScore);
            mRelative.addView(mButtons);
            setContentView(mRelative);
            this.setupTitleAndScore();
        }

    }
}
```

this is the final piece.

Comment: I almost forgot to mention the activity that I'm trying to launch doesn't show. I'm trying show the fragment in the activity at the activitys launch  but the activity doesn't even show. the fragment code seems to be running in the background. I'm trying to start one activity  from another activity entirely.

Comment: I see 'on attach' and 'on create view' in the logs before the fragment disappears. I have not figured out why it closes, though.

Comment: the problem was a BroadcastReceiver that was trying to modify an array adapter for a list view. The broadcast reciever is not shown in ANY of the code I posted. For brevity I will not post it now. The interesting thing is that the code worked when launched from one activity, but did not work when launched from another activity.